# Flutter collapsing container

Tags: android, flutter

I'm migrating an application from nativ android to flutter. I'm struggling to achieved a "collapsing container" into my flutter application.

I have a first part with a background image and some buttons that I would like to collapse when the screen is scrolled until a tab bar. When I reach the tab bar, the scroll stops and then I'm able to scroll through the content of each tab.

There is a small gif to show what I'm tring to achieved :

[image: gif of the collapsing container]

I saw a lot of tutorial using SilverAppBar but I'm not sure that tring to force my container inside an appbar would be the best way to do it.

Do you have any ideas on how I can achieved this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Android** the **CollapsingToolbar** UI component is available within the design-support library, while in iOS there is no official UI component, but there are libraries that help us to do the same.
In order to do the same in Flutter, we need to use the Widget called `SliverAppBar` together with `FlexibleSpaceBar` as a child.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text("Collapsing Toolbar",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      )),
                  background: Image.network(
                    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350",
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Sample Text"),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: Giff]

For more infromation visit [here](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe)

Comment: Thank you ! 
I used the `SliverAppBar` with the `FlexibleSpaceBar ` like you recommend and I managed to achieve want I wanted.